# Why the question about C language ideology is closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I've asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890817/what-is-the-ideology-of-c-programming-language that was closed as off-topic, and I think it is certainly not.

- "software tools commonly used by programmers" - language is a tool used by programmers and its implementations are software tools used by programmers, and an understanding of an ideology is needed to write good programs.
- "matters that are unique to the programming profession" - surely it is.

UPDATE: Yes I've read the FAQ and feel that the question is not something dim, but a question about the daily tool - C language.

Comment: If you write the quesion well, you may get answers on programming.se

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read a bit more of the faq please, specifically the next section at https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

> **You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.**
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

Comment: Have you read it a little further: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual ... <b>
However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK."</b> And also please read the 2 sections I've mentioned in the question description.

Comment: @outmind If you ask 3 different people what the ideology of C is, you will likely get 3+ different answers.  That pushes the question towards being unanswerable.

Comment: @outmind it is radically and definitively off-topic; a fine subjective discussion topic but *such discussions do not belong on Stack Overflow*.

Comment: JeffAtwood: Is it just an radical and definitive opinion? Where are arguments?

Comment: Jonsca: Thanks. Yes - it feels like unanswerable, but it nots. As you can build several algorithms for the same problem. Some of them would be correct, some of them would be wrong. And I've marked it with "language-history" tag.

Comment: @outmind  Such an open-ended question is in no way analogous to an algorithm question.  Entire books could be written on ideology, so you can't expect a closed-form answer to it within the Q/A format.  To your latter point, there are lots of tags left over from earlier times, that does not justify making more questions to suit those "legacy" tags.

Comment: @jonsca: Entire books could be written on an ideology, but not C ideology. I think that each programming language has several main ideas in its core, not several books. For example C is procedural and imperative, but i don't think that they are its features as too many langs are procedural and imperative.

Answer (score 4):

Read a few lines further down in the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

Your question is definitely open ended.  A more appropriate place for it could be on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), but it may be too subjective for that site as well (see their [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)).

Comment: Yes - I see. After some discussion with other I feel that probably I should reformulate my question to ask for main concepts of C.